# Installing RS2008 against SQL Server 2000

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2000, ssrs-2008

Is there any chance of installing Reporting Services 2008 against an instance of SQL Server 2000? The docs clearly state that only SQL Server 2005 or 2008 are supported, but I thought I should ask anyway, for ways to bypass this limitation.

I should mention that I am not talking about the data source for my reports (which is a remote data source that can be any type of sql server). I am interested in the databases where the report server stores its things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the reportserver and reportservertempdb REQUIRE 2005 or 2008. You could source data for your reports from a 2000 instance, but your reporting services databases need to be 2005 or 2008.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157285.aspx and read the section on Database Server Version Requirements

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this would work, however reporting services also depends on the SQL Server Agent service (for subscriptions) as well as the relational databases, so both would need to be compatible. If you have Reporting Services 2008 then you (or your organisation) must own a SQL Server 2008 license of some sort, therefore I cannot see why you would ever want to do this since you can install the SQL 2008 database engine to support your report server (on the same server, otherwise you would need an additional license).

Bear in mind that as of April 2008 SQL Server 2000 is no longer in mainstream support from Microsoft, so you should avoid implementing new infrastructure or functionality using this version wherever possible. The configuration you describe above, even if you got it to work, would be unsupported by Microsoft and probably all ISVs and partners.